# C++ extraneous for loop needed for program to run successfully

Tags: c++, loops, binary

Before we start, yes this is homework, no i'm not trying to get someone else to do my homework. I was given a problem to have someone enter a binary number of up to 7 digits and simply change that number from binary to decimal. Though i'm most certainly not using the most efficient/best method, i'm sure I can make it work. Lets look at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char numbers[8];
    int number = 0, error = 0;

    cout << "Please input a binary number (up to 7 digits)\nBinary: ";

    cin.get(numbers, 8);
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');

    for (int z = 7; z >= 0; z--){}
    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0, x = 7; x >= 0; x--, i++){
        if (numbers[x] <= 0){ // if that is an empty space in the array.
            i--;
        }
        else if (numbers[x] == '1'){
            number += pow(2, i);
        }
        else if (numbers[x] != '0'){ // if something other than a 0, 1, or empty space is in the array.
            error = 1;
            x = -1;
        }
    }
    if (error){ // if a char other than 0 or 1 was input this should print.
        cout << "That isn't a binary number.\n";
    }
    else{
        cout << numbers << " is " << number << " in decimal.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this code it works perfectly. However in a quick look through the code there is this "for (int z = 7; z >= 0; z--){}" which appears to do absolutely nothing. However if I delete or comment it out my program decides that any input is not a binary number. If someone could tell me why this loop is needed and/or how to remove it, it would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What about using a debugger to step through first, to check what's actually going on.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the `numbers` array will be all zeros after the end of the string, but only the one character immediately after the string will be set to zero.  Try initializing your array:  `char numbers[8] = {}`.

Comment: printing variables at various stages is also usually helpful in cases like this. You're quite right that the line should do nothing, which implies that something more subtle is going on. Looking at this code, my money is on a buffer overflow (terminating null-byte?)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Good first thought, though it is even more puzzling then that, when I debug it, it works. However if I just run it normally, it prints that it isn't a binary number.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I totally agree, that is the reason why I placed the loop there originally.

Comment: @VaughnCato Just like that, that totally fixed it, thanks! But one quick question, why does the for loop fix that issue? Shouldn't it just continue on and have the same error later on?

Comment: Reading an uninitialized value is undefined behavior, so all bets are off.

Comment: Don't use `pow()` for base 2.  You can bit shift integers with the `<<` operator, and floating point can have its binary point moved using `ldexp()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop here:

```
for (int i = 0, x = 7; x >= 0; x--, i++){
    if (numbers[x] <= 0){ // reads numbers[7] the first time around, but
                          // what if numbers[7] hasn't been set?
        i--;
    }
```

you are potentially reading an uninitialized value if the input was less than seven characters long.  This is because the `numbers` array is uninitialized, and `cin.get` only puts a null terminator after the last character in the string, not for the entire rest of the array.  One simple way to fix it is to initialize your array:

```
char numbers[8] = {};
```

As to why the extraneous loop fixes it -- reading an uninitialized value is undefined behavior, which means there are no guarantees about what the program will do.